# Slow download speed despite of fast connection

Tags: linux, networking, performance, tcp

My new VDSL internet connection happens to have ~72 MBit/s downstream, ~30 MBit/s upstream and ~22 ms RTT (to the example server used below). I got these numbers using iperf (test duration: 60 seconds, parallel connections: 10).

*But when I try do do a normal download of a big file, the connection is nowhere near those numbers and I get only about 8-10 Mbit/s.*

I'm using wget to download `http://ftp.knoppix.nl/os/Linux/distr/knoppix-dvd/KNOPPIX_V7.6.1DVD-2016-01-16-DE.iso` here for illustration, but I also tested other servers (including my own root server) and curl instead of wget.

The interesting part is: When the download starts it ramps up to about 1.5 MB/s, then drops to about 1 MB/s before slowly ramping up to 1.5 MB/s again. This procedure is repeating over and over again. You can get the corresponding wireshark dump file here (size: 34.5 MB): `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/d64cb0a2/stackoverflow/knoppix_test.pcapng.gz`

If I download the file on my root server which has a 1 GBit/s line and ~ 10 ms RTT I get about 80 MB/s download speed for the same http url which is much more.

**My question is:**

Is there anything I can do to speed up my connection?

**And next question:** this even holds, when I try to download a file hosted on my own root server. If this can only changed on the server side, what would I have to do to tweak my own server appropriately?

Comment: Have you tried to download it with a download manager it might be how many host the server is providing you to download from the more the hosts the more the speed it is

Comment: Well, as I wrote, the download speed is **much** higher when I use the exactly same tool (wget) to load the same url using my root server. So in both cases (home server versus root server) there is no download manager involved, but the speed is very different. And in my opinion my download speed at home shouldn't be so slow compared to my root server when loading the exact same file using the exact same tool.